# Logout just redirect to login page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created function to control login and logout for the user like this :

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Control_auth extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library(array('session'));
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('model_user');
    session_start();
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('view_login');
}

public function check_login() {
    $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password')
    );

    $hasil = $this->model_user->check_user($data);

    if ($hasil->num_rows() == 1) {

        $akses = $this->input->post('level');

        foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess) {
            $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'logging';
            $sess_data['username'] = $sess->username;
            $sess_data['level'] = $sess->level;

            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
        }

        /* administrator */
        if ($this->session->userdata('level') == 1 && $akses == 'Administrator') { 
            redirect('administrator/control_admin');
        } else {
            echo " <script>alert('Gagal Login: Pilih Hak Akses');history.go(-1);</script>";
        }
        /* member */
        if ($this->session->userdata('level') == 4 && $akses == 'User') {
            redirect('control_member');
        }            
    } else { //false
        echo " <script>alert('Gagal Login: Cek username , password, dan hak akses Anda !');history.go(-1);</script>";
    }
}

public function logout() {
    $this->session->unset_userdata(array('username' => '', 'logged_in' => FALSE));
    $this->session->userdata = array();
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('control_auth');
}
```

}

Thhe problem is, when I logout, it just redirect to login page again. So, in browser like firefox, when the arrow history is clicked, it still can accessed the main page. Any solution will be apriciated...

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this code in your control_admin function to check if this user logged in or not.

```
    if(!empty($this->session->userdata['username'])){
   //add your code here if logged in
         $this->load->view('yourpagename');
      }else{
       redirect('control_auth');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clear out cache when logout

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into every admin controller, for login validation.

```
//check login status if not login user will redirect to htt://heloo.com/dboxadmin.php
if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=NULL)&&($this->session->userdata('level')!=NULL)){
    //user already login
    //add filtering query by level user. $this->session->userdata('level');
}else{
    redirect("dboxadmin.php"); //your login controller
}

//login controller
if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=NULL)&&($this->session->userdata('level')!=NULL)){ 
    //user already login and redirect to dashboard
    redirect("dashboard.php");
}else{
    //add code for check, if post call login query
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        //your login query 
    }else{
        //show login form
        $this->load->view('login-form');
    }   
}

//logout controller add
$this->session->sess_destroy();
redirect("dboxadmin.php"); //your login controller
```

Read this document : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
session_destroy();
```

in your logout function and try....

Answer (score 0):

you complete the whole process by making a  helper . please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667810/session-timeout-in-codeigniter  and dont forget to rename $config['sess_cookie_name']